# Retrieving the first list only (JSON-Python)

Tags: python, json, list, indexing

I have a complicated JSON object with dictionary information about words and I want to get only the synonyms. I managed to retrieve them, but some words have two or more lists of synonyms (since they can be for example a verb and a noun at the same time). I would like to get only the first list of synonyms. Here is what I've done:

```
import requests
import json
with open(r'C:\Users...') as file:
    list = []
    for line in file.readlines():
        list += line.split() 
    for keyword in list:
        print(keyword)
        ship_api_url = "https://..."
        request_data = requests.get(ship_api_url)
        data = request_data.text
        parsed = json.loads(data)
        # print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=3))
        for item in parsed:
            print(item['meta']['syns'][0])
```

And here's what I get - note that the word 'watch' has three lists of synonyms, the word 'create' has only one list of synonyms and the word 'created' has two lists of synonyms:

```
watch
['custodian', 'guard', 'guardian', 'keeper', 'lookout', 'minder', 'picket', 'sentinel', 'sentry', 'warden', 'warder', 'watcher', 'watchman']
['eye', 'follow', 'observe']
['anticipate', 'await', 'expect', 'hope (for)']
create
['beget', 'breed', 'bring', 'bring about', 'bring on', 'catalyze', 'cause', 'do', 'draw on', 'effect', 'effectuate', 'engender', 'generate', 'induce', 'invoke', 'make', 'occasion', 'produce', 'prompt', 'result (in)', 'spawn', 'translate (into)', 'work', 'yield']
created
['begot', 'bred', 'brought', 'brought about', 'brought on', 'catalyzed', 'caused', 'did', 'drew on', 'effected', 'effectuated', 'engendered', 'generated', 'induced', 'invoked', 'made', 'occasioned', 'produced', 'prompted', 'resulted (in)', 'spawned', 'translated (into)', 'worked', 'yielded']
['beget', 'breed', 'bring', 'bring about', 'bring on', 'catalyze', 'cause', 'do', 'draw on', 'effect', 'effectuate', 'engender', 'generate', 'induce', 'invoke', 'make', 'occasion', 'produce', 'prompt', 'result (in)', 'spawn', 'translate (into)', 'work', 'yield']
```

If I add another [0] after the [0] I already have, I get the first word of each list, not the first whole list as I need...

Comment: Just add a `break` statement after the `print(item['meta']['syns'][0])` and stop the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot! With the break statement, I get the exact result I want. But I still would like to know how to select one list out of lists...

Comment: The first list is `item['meta']['syns'][0]`, you can access elements in it by indexing them like you did when you added a `[0]` as described in your question. It's a list, so you can do other things, like iterate over its contents via a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, you want to do something like this:

```
import requests
import json
with open(r'C:\Users...') as file:
    list = []
    for line in file.readlines():
        list += line.split() 
    for keyword in list:
        print(keyword)
        ship_api_url = "https://..."
        request_data = requests.get(ship_api_url)
        data = request_data.text
        parsed = json.loads(data)
        # print(json.dumps(parsed, indent=3))
        for item in parsed:
            for i in item['meta']['syns']:
                print(item['meta']['syns'][i])
```

Also, don't name your variable `list` as it is reserved variable in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the variable naming tip. Unfortunately, the code you sent me doesn't work, I get: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment by martineau, I solved the problem by adding a break statement after the `print(item['meta']['syns'][0])` to stop the loop.